# Is there any way to have a button outside of the elfinder element that presses "select files"

Tags: javascript, elfinder

I'm trying to get the button in the bottom that says "kies bestanden" to trigger select files in elfinder. Because our customer thinks the little arrow button is too small.

The elfinder element is in an iframe, which complicates things. Is there any way to do it?

[image: elfinder window]

Comment: If the page and the iframe content are from the same origin (protocol, domain, port), you may be able to access the `iframe` DOM from the page via, for example, `window.frames[0].document`. Executing scripts in that context would have to be done via script injection.

Comment: Yes they are from the same origin. And I've tried what you described by trying to programmatically pressing that cursor button. But that does not seem to work.